# Paperclip browse button customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip to attach logo picture for a model its working fine but I want to customize browse button I want to apply some classes on it and want to change the text from 'BROWSE..' to 'Add logo'. How can I do that. What I need to change in this line

```
<%= f.file_field :logo, class: "button btn-sm text-center" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Browse" button is default to browser. 
In order to customize that one, please try this:

Get your [boostrap-filestyle.js](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/js/bootstrap-filestyle.js) file. 
Place this js file in your **app/assets/javascript** folder and mark it require  in your **application.js**

```
//= require bootstrap-filestyle
```

Next in your view try this:

```
  <%= f.file_field :banner, class: 'filestyle',  
       :'data-classButton' => 'btn btn-primary',
       :'data-input' => 'false', classIcon:  'icon-plus', 
       :'data-buttonText' => 'Your label here'  %>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Amazing it works please can you help If I just want to hide this button and want a small preview how can i do that?

Comment: Sorry, did not get you.  What do you mean by "a small prview"  ?

Comment: forget about the preview how can i hide the button??

Comment: With above code, you can change the button text to your desired text and add styling on top of it. I am unable to understand what exactly you are trying to hide here ?